# Unknown feature (Facet[kotlin-language]) covered by non-bundled plugin detected

Tags: android, kotlin

I just update my Android Studio to 2.3 and after it got message "Unknown feature (Facet[kotlin-language]) covered by non-bundled plugin detected."

Is this, still issus? https://twitter.com/kotlin/status/797111726516879360

Thanks

Comment: Kotlin is compatible with Android Studio 2.3 now. If you have Kotlin configured in your project properly, try updating your Kotlin plugin or doing an invalidate cache/restart.

Comment: working like a charm!!!

Answer (score 3):

*[The text of this answer was originally written by zsmb13]*

Kotlin is compatible with Android Studio 2.3 now. If you have Kotlin configured in your project properly, try updating your Kotlin plugin or doing an invalidate cache/restart.